# RAM version in smartphone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

How can i find or check RAM version of my smartphone ,am using Samsung Galaxy,is there some secret code to find that?
Already i have tried the code : `*#*#3264#*#*`  but no help.
please help me sort this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to find the ROM version or RAM version??

Comment: RAM details..like manufacture / version

Comment: Those are your device specific details.

Comment: yes i was able to see the RAM size ,but was unable to find the indepth system infos of RAM

Comment: Try going into 'About phone' option under your settings. Hope that meets your need.

Comment: @HussainChachuliya If you happen to have Linux, you can run `dmidecode` and see the details like RAM Manufacturer, its type, serial no, asset tag, etc. I think OP is trying to look such info. Unfortunately,  "About Phone" doesn't hold this info :-)

Comment: @Firelord I was confused as to what the OP is trying  out.. that's why I mentioned the default way of finding device info.

Comment: Actually im trying to find detailed info on RAM , as we do in windows OS using msconfig .. please correct me if im wrong

Comment: @utility Are you sure about `msconfig`? This command doesn't show any system information at all other than boot parameters and services. It has links to various options under "Tools" followed by their corresponding commands. The closest I found was `msinfo32.exe`.

Comment: I think he means ROM

Comment: no RAM ,and sorry for msconfig,i actually wanted to make reference to dxdiag in windows